# I am trying to upload multiple files using spring mvc,Only first file is uploading

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I am trying to upload multiple files using Spring MVC,the first file uploads fine,where from second onwards getting org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet noHandlerFound
No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [user2-160x160.jpg] in DispatcherServlet with name 'spring'

Here is my controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/uploadFile", method = RequestMethod.POST) 
public ModelAndView viewProducts(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,@RequestParam CommonsMultipartFile[] fileUpload) throws IllegalStateException, IOException 
        {       
            ModelAndView model= null;
             String saveDirectory = "E:/Test/Upload/";
            model = new ModelAndView("user/dashboard/profile-view");

            System.out.println("In New");
            if (fileUpload != null && fileUpload.length > 0) {
                for (CommonsMultipartFile aFile : fileUpload){

                    System.out.println("Saving file: " + aFile.getOriginalFilename());

                    if (!aFile.getOriginalFilename().equals("")) {
                        aFile.transferTo(new File(saveDirectory + aFile.getOriginalFilename()));
                    }
                }
            }

            // returns to the view "Result"

            return model;
        }
```

My servlet:

```
<mvc:annotation-driven />

<bean id="jspViewResolver"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="viewClass"
        value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    <property name="order" value="1" />
```

```
<bean id="multipartResolver"
    class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver">
    <!-- max upload size in bytes -->
    <property name="maxUploadSize" value="20971520" /> <!-- 20MB -->

    <!-- max size of file in memory (in bytes) -->
    <property name="maxInMemorySize" value="1048576" /> <!-- 1MB -->



</bean>


<bean
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleMappingExceptionResolver">
    <property name="exceptionMappings">
        <props>
            <prop key="java.lang.Exception">Error</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>
```

My jsp looks like:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" method="post" action="uploadFile" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                              <div class="box-body">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                  <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Business Registration Proof&#10067;</label>
                                  <div class="col-sm-10">
                                    <input type="file" class="form-control" id="bus_reg_proof" name="fileUpload" size="50" placeholder="Choose file">
                                  </div>
                                </div>

                                    <div class="form-group">
                                  <label for="inputPassword3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Business PAN&#10067;</label>
                                  <div class="col-sm-10">
                                    <input type="file" class="form-control" id="bus_pan" name="fileUpload" size="50" placeholder="Choose file">
                                  </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                  <label for="inputPassword3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Company's Bank Account Statement with Address</label>
                                  <div class="col-sm-10">
                                    <input type="file" class="form-control" id="com_bank_acc_st" name="fileUpload" size="50" placeholder="Choose file">
                                  </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                  <label for="inputPassword3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Authorised Signatory Address Proof&#10067;</label>
                                  <div class="col-sm-10">
                                    <input type="file" class="form-control" id="auth_sign_add_proof" name="fileUpload" size="50" placeholder="Choose file">
                                  </div>
                                </div>
                                     <!-- /.box-body -->
                              </div>
                              <div class="box-footer">
                                 <input type="submit"  class="btn btn-info pull-right" "></button>
                              </div><!-- /.box-footer -->
```

Comment: The second time you submit a form? Or multiple files in a single form? At least your action is wrong! Currently you have a relative URL, which means the second time (after uploading) you submit it will submit to `/uploadFile/uploadFile`. Your controller is also flawed you should be programming against the interface `MultipartFile` not the concrete `CommonsMultipartFile`.

Comment: Multiple files in a single form!

Comment: Can you please be more specific.what i need to do now?

Comment: Read the comment... Also you haven't posted your configuration on how you configure the annotation driven nature of Spring MVC. Also first fix the issues as mentioned before.

Comment: Problem with jar files,I have created a separate project for file uploads,works fine...when i integrated the upload files to my project problem occurs...and i tried removing jar files of my project,uploads works fine again..is there any solution for this?

Comment: Still your code is wrong, solve that as that is imho your actual issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To upload a list of files you need to wrap all those files in an object which you will send/recover from the jsp.
Lets imagine a object called FilesWrapper and should looks like this:

```
public class FilesWrapper{
    private List<CommonsMultipartFile> files;
    //getters - setters
}
```

Then in your GET method to draw the page you need to send that object in the ModelAndView

```
modelAndView.add("filesWrapper", new FilesWrapper());
```

In your jsp form. You should send an array of files, then the attribute name should be an array.

```
<form:form class="form-horizontal" method="post" action="uploadFile" enctype="multipart/form-data" modelAttribute="filesWrapper">


<div class="col-sm-10">
   <input type="file" class="form-control" id="bus_reg_proof" name="files[0]" size="50" placeholder="Choose file">
</div>
<div class="col-sm-10">
   <input type="file" class="form-control" id="bus_reg_proof" name="files[1]" size="50" placeholder="Choose file">
</div>
```

...

And in your controller method POST

```
@RequestParam("filesWrapepr") FilesWrapper filesWrapper)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer,I have tried it.getting Required [Lorg.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartFile; parameter 'fileUpload' is not present

Comment: @ManjunathReddy Try adding the change i added to the controller with the name of the parameter.

Comment: I have tried adding it to my controller,Getting Same error message

Comment: @ManjunathReddy I edited my response, you cant send a list to the POST method, spring cant handle it correctly, you need to wrap all those date into an object.

Comment: Problem with jar files,I have created a separate project for file uploads,works fine...when i integrated the upload files to my project problem occurs...and i tried removing jar files of my project,uploads works fine again..is there any solution for this?

Comment: I dont see the relation with those jar files, what jars are involve?

Comment: Uploads requires spring-beans-3.2.0.RC2,spring-context-3.2.0.RC2 e.t.c. jars,where my project requires org.springframework.asm-3.0.1.RELEASE-A.jar,e.t.c jars...when i remove org. jars from my lib folder uploads are working fine,but i need those jars for my project

Comment: Take into account in the solution i give you i am using spring MVC, thats why i used the tag form:form, or modelAttribute,...if you dont want to use those spring tags, you have to modify your jsp file to use standard dom tags